# Gatsby x contentful error when building, problems with gatsby-node.js

Tags: node.js, gatsby, netlify, contentful

sinds a few days I am getting a building error with netlify.
I am quite new to Gatbsy so I couldn't resolve it by my self. I hope you guys can help me out with this.

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createPage' of 'boundActionCreators' a s it is undefined.

**Gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
};

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const path = require(`path`);
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(`
      {
        allContentfulProduct {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              slug
              name
              introTitle
              description2title
              description1title
              category {
                name
                slug
              }
              introDescription {
                internal {
                  content
                }
              }
              image {
                file {
                  url
                }
              }
              images {
                id
                file {
                  url
                }
              }
              description1 {
                internal {
                  content
                }
              }
              description2 {
                internal {
                  content
                }
              }
              specs
              pdf {
                file {
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `).then((result) => {
      result.data.allContentfulProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `systems/producten/${node.slug}`,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/systems/producten/product.js`),
          context: {
            slug: node.slug,
            product: node,
          },
        });
      });
      resolve();
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    reject();
  });
};
```

This is the error when building
[image: netlify building error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring in the "old-fashioned" way. Change it to:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const path = require(`path`);
  const { createPage } = actions;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(`
      {
        allContentfulProduct {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              slug
              name
              introTitle
              description2title
              description1title
              category {
                name
                slug
              }
              introDescription {
                internal {
                  content
                }
              }
              image {
                file {
                  url
                }
              }
              images {
                id
                file {
                  url
                }
              }
              description1 {
                internal {
                  content
                }
              }
              description2 {
                internal {
                  content
                }
              }
              specs
              pdf {
                file {
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `).then((result) => {
      result.data.allContentfulProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `systems/producten/${node.slug}`,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/systems/producten/product.js`),
          context: {
            slug: node.slug,
            product: node,
          },
        });
      });
      resolve();
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    reject();
  });
};
```

Just changing `boundActionCreators` by `actions` should do the trick in version 2 onwards, as you can see in [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs).

---

Outside the scope of the question, in addition, in your `gatsby-node.js` you have:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
};
```

`/bad-module/` is the name of the folder inside `node_modules` which contains the offending module that breaks your compilation when some third-dependency module uses `window` (or other global objects) in the SSR. It's a regular expression, that's why is between slashes (`/`) and it should match some folder, otherwise, you can remove it.

Regarding the new issue, it has nothing to do with the previous workaround. The new issue is caused by an undefined property. If there's a possibility that your data comes `undefined` or `null`, add a condition like:

```
{category && <span>{category.name}</span>}
```

Comment: Hi Ferran, yes indeed this was the problem, gracias por eso!
But now I have another building issue.

Comment: @VictorLaforga Updated. It has nothing to do with the previous issue. Try building locally your project before pushing it to Netlify. This error should appear locally too.